# how to access length queue for each node in NS2

Tags: c++, ns2

In NS2 we can defined queue length for the node by adding  the definitions in tcl:

$ns_ node-config \

```
               -llType         LL

               -ifqType        "Queue/DropTail/PriQueue"

               -ifqLen         50
```

then in c++ we access this by use for example in the case of AODV or AOMDV:

ifqueue->queue_length()

but I think this is not for specific node

my question is how I access the queue length for each node using node address during routing discovery